# Sprites not displaying correctly in IE 6,7,8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, css-sprites

:-)
Smiley - face at the start there, but this is really irritating for me. 
As you see from the title, THE POSITIONING OF THE ELEMENTS IN IE 6,7 AND 8(At least) is off.  I'm including the direct url : http://evolvedtools.com/Genr8Mobi.html.
Now this page is normally a redirect from a full - size page, and on a reasonable browser (Read: everything bar Internet explorer) ,everything renders well. The page is meant for small format browser or mobile, but it has css for desktop also in separate stylesheet. Resize your browser window to see how it works.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>Genr8</title>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link href="PuzzleMobileIE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 649px), screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-device-height:320px)" id="stylesheet-PIEmob" >
<link href="DesktopIE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 651px) and (min-height: 650px)" id="stylesheet-DTIE" >
<![endif]-->
<link href="PuzzleMobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 649px), screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-device-height:320px)" id="stylesheet-Pmob" >

<link href="PuzzlePad.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and  (min-width: 650px) and (max-width: 1024px)" id="stylesheet-Pad" >

<link href="Desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 651px) and (min-height: 650px)" id="stylesheet-DT" >

<Script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/js/Respond/Respond-master/dest/respond.min.js"></Script>
<Script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript Cookie Script.js"></Script>
<!--<Script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/puzPlugin_56.png','images/HomeButton_03.png','images/AnimasjonMotsatt.gif','images/puzzleGenr8SpriteFull.png','images/Spritepuz1.png')">



<div class="puzzle">
<div class="puzzle2">

<div id="homeGenr8"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/HomeButton_03.png" alt="HomeG8MobAlt" name="homeGenr8" width="100%" id="homeGenr82" ></a></div>

<div id="Genr8Flash"><a href="FillingIn4.html"><img src="images/AnimasjonMotsatt.gif" alt="FlashG8MobAlt" name="Genr8Flash" width="100%" id="Genr8Flash2" ></a></div>

<div id="puzzleK"><a href="Plugins/Genr8OldPlusNew.rar"><img src="images/puzPlugin_56.png" alt="PluginsG8Alt" name="puzzleK" width="100%" class="AllElements" id="puzzleK2" ></a></div>

</div>
<ul id="navlist">
  <li id="Intro"><a href="Genr8PageIntro.php"></a></li>
  <li id="Source"><a href="SourceCode.html"></a></li>
 </ul>
<ul id="navlist2">
  <li id="genr82001"><a href="GENR8litt/genr8MartinHemberg.pdf"></a></li>
  <li id="compDebug"><a href="CompileAndDebug.html"></a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="navlist3">
<li id="pWorkings"><a href="PluginWorkings.html"></a></li>
 </ul>
  <ul id="navlist4">
<li id="analysis"><a href="Genr8Analysis.html"></a></li>
 </ul>
  <ul id="navlist5">
 <li id="g8new"><a href="Genr82011.php"></a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>

  <Script type="text/javascript" src="BodyScriptGenr8.js"></Script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see from the header, I have tried to include a separate stylesheet for IE8 and lower, but there seems to be no difference. I am using IETester with debugbar to test.
I have tried to change everything in the css, but nothing registers. THE MAIN question though remains: Why o why will the sprites not position right with older IE ?

css for the "mobile" or small windowed desktop:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@media screen and (max-width: 649px), screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-device-height:320px){

    body {
    background-color: #000!important;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: #000;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: #000;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: #000;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: #000;
}

img {
    border:0;
 }

.puzzle {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width:290px;
    height:282px;
    margin-left: -145px;
    margin-top: -141px;
    /*margin-left: auto;*/
    /*left: auto;
    top: auto;*/
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-image: url(images/puzzleGenr8SpriteFullMob.png);
    /*_background-image: url(images/puzzleGenr8SpriteFullMob.gif);*/ /*IE6*/
    background-size:290px 282px!important;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.puzzle2 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display:block;
    background-color: #000!important;
}
#homeGenr8 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 28px;
    width: 69px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    visibility: visible;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
}
/*html>body #homeGenr8
{
width: auto;
height: auto;
min-width: 69px;
min-height: 28px;
}
*/
#Genr8Flash {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 28px;
    width: 62px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 228px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
}

#puzzleK {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    height: 28px;
    width: 63px;
    left: 227px;
    top: 254px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
}


#navlist{position:relative;}
#navlist li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:absolute;top:-8px;}
#navlist li, #navlist a{height:23px;display:block;}
/*#backG{left:0px;width:580px;height:563px;}
#backG{background:url('images/puzzleGenr8SpriteFull.png') 0 0;}*/

#Intro{left:85px;width:50px;height:23px;}
#Intro{background:url('images/puzzleGenr8SpriteFull.png') -83px -5px;background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#Intro a:hover{background: url('images/Spritepuz1Mob.gif') -83px -5px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#Source{left:152px;width:58px;height:14px;}
#Source{background:url('images/puzzleGenr8SpriteFull.png') -152px -8px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#Source a:hover{background: url('images/Spritepuz1Mob.gif') -152px -8px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#navlist2{position:relative;}
#navlist2 li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:absolute;top:22px;}
#navlist2 li, #navlist2 a{height:28px;display:block;}

#genr82001{left:31px;width:50px;height:27px;}
#genr82001{background:url('images/puzzleGenr8SpriteFull.png') -28px -38px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#genr82001 a:hover{background: url('images/Spritepuz1.gif') -28px -38px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#compDebug{left:220px;width:60px;height:20px;}
#compDebug{background:url('images/puzzleGenr8SpriteFull.png') -220px -38px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#compDebug a:hover{background: url('images/Spritepuz1Mob.gif') -220px -38px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#navlist3{position:relative;}
#navlist3 li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:absolute;top:63px;}
#navlist3 li, #navlist3 a{height:23px;display:block;}

#pWorkings{left:147px;width:55px;height:23px;}
#pWorkings{background:url('images/puzzleGenr8SpriteFull.png') -147px -75px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#pWorkings a:hover{background: url('images/Spritepuz1Mob.gif') -147px -75px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#navlist4{position:relative;}
#navlist4 li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:absolute;top:105px;}
#navlist4 li, #navlist4 a{height:27px;display:block;}

#analysis{left:25px;width:53px;height:23px;}
#analysis{background:url('images/puzzleGenr8SpriteFull.png') -20px -120px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#analysis a:hover{background: url('images/Spritepuz1Mob.gif') -20px -120px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#navlist5{position:relative;}
#navlist5 li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:absolute;top:221px;}
#navlist5 li, #navlist5 a{height:27px;display:block;}

#g8new{left:12px;width:55px;height:23px;}
#g8new{background:url('images/puzzleGenr8SpriteFull.png') -7px -232px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
#g8new a:hover{background: url('images/Spritepuz1Mob.gif') -7px -232px;
background-size: 290px 282px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

}
```

I get warnings for background-size in the css-file, but how would I go about correcting my css/html for this to display correctly in IE6,7 and 8 ?
Just to be clear - I am not going to change all my html and css just for the page to display with old IE, but I would really appreciate a little insight :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@media` is not supported by IE8 or earlier. All your CSS code is inside an `@media` block, and thus won't be seen by these browsers.

You can use a polyfill like [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to handle this which will probably help (although I can't vouch for the performance if you need to support browsers as old as IE8).

But to be honest most of that CSS code shouldn't be inside an `@media` block anyway; media blocks should contain only the styles which you want to be different from normal for a given screen size. Everything that's the same as normal should be kept outside of the media block.

If you just do that, there's a good chance that you may not even need to worry about respond.js if you can get the default CSS outside of the media blocks to be how you want IE6/7/8 to behave; then the media blocks can just be for overrides for browsers in different sized windows to that.

[EDIT]

You've edited the question, and I now see that you're already using respond.js, so hopefully this means that the above is not the main issue. I still think you need to reduce the size of your media query code though; there's a lot of CSS in there which really shouldn't be in a media query.

The other problem you've got is that you're using `background-size` for your sprite image.

This is another CSS feature that is not supported by IE8 and earlier, and this will definitely break your sprites. In fact it weakens the whole concept of using background images for sprites in IE8.

Again, there are polyfills for this feature, you can you get it working in IE8 if you're determined. [See here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#backgrounds-and-borders-spec) for links to a few possible options. I usually recommend CSS3Pie for this kind of thing, but as you can see it's not the only option, so pick the one that works best for you.

Always bear in mind that the more polyfill scripts you use, and the more you're asking them to do, the more of a performance impact it'll have.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply:-) If you look you see the inclusion of respond.js in the header. And when you say that IE8 and earlier doesn't support @media, what exactly does that entail, because clearly the css is being partly applied. How would you say is the best way to set up the css in this case ? Problem for me seems to be there are no "normal" cases, everything needs to be stretched and resized and adjusted.

Comment: Would the best solution be standard stylesheet without media block + extra @media for the lt IE 9 + extra for the desktop ? I don't want to redirect back to another page just because someone might stretch their browser viewport( Or set their mobile browser to a different zoom level )

Comment: Hi. The inclusion of respond.js wasn't in the question when I posted the answer, but fair enough if you've already got that, then that's a good start.

Comment: Re your second comment, yes, the best way to do media queries is to have as much of your CSS as possible outside of the media queries. The media block should contain the bare minimum of code. Particularly for IE<=8, this will have a noticable performance impact if nothing else.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the answer with a whole load of new stuff. Hope this hits the mark better than my first attempt :)

Comment: Great feedback ! Thanx! I cut down the markup to the minimum, put "normal" css outside media query, and I'm going to have a look at the link. I can see the problem of the background-size issue in the mapping of the image, but when I drop down in image size and delete the "background-size" attribute to get rid of the issue, I still have two problems: The first is that the image becomes somewhat unreadable for menu-use. Second, there is still a persistent offset problem between IE 6,7 to 8 to other browsers. All other browsers generally display well, but IE..... :-(

Comment: Great link, I've got a lot of testing to do :-)